# how to Read JSON object using ajax from a python wsgi application

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, json

So here is my python application.

```
from wsgiref.simple_server import make_server
import json

def application(environ, start_response):
   result = [{"name":"John Johnson","street":"Oslo West 555","age":33}]
   response_body = json.dumps(result)
   status = '200 OK'
   response_headers = [('Content-Type', 'text/plain'),
                  ('Content-Length', str(len(response_body)))]
   start_response(status, response_headers)
   return [response_body]

httpd = make_server('localhost',8051,application)
httpd.handle_request()
```

So Now all I want is to get the return value to display on the web.
I read there is function jQuery.getJSON. but I don't quite understand how it works.
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Thanks.

Comment: Which part about it do you not understand? Your question is rather vague.

Comment: True. I am not really familiar with JS/JQuery. I just wanna know how to use the $.getJSON to display the JSON object on the web.So when python app is running, I can open my browser, type in localhost:8051, then it will display the json object. so instead of doing this, I wanna open a web page, then it will display the same thing. Sorry about my explanation, hope it will make it a little clearer. thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8051').success(function(data) {
    //here `data` will be your `result` in your python application
});
```

If your jQuery version < 1.5

```
$.getJSON('http://localhost:8051', function(data){
    // data == result
});
```

PS: if you return a json object, you'd better set the `Content-Type` to `application/json`

Comment: I am sorry I can not upvote the answer because I do not have 15 reputation.

Comment: you can accept the answer. anyway i'm pleased this can help you.

Comment: Accepted. Thank you very much for the help. Pity I can't vote yet. once I reach 15 rep, I will come back and upvote it. Thanks a mill.